# Use of the verb "edge"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs, idioms

How clear are these sentences?

> Fighters are often edged to injuries.
> She is prone to edge herself to threat.
> She has started to edge herself to feel the wind.

In slang, the verb *to edge* has the meaning *to make someone or something continuously be at a point just before culminating in something* (e.g. in an orgasm, an online order completion, or emotional outburst). [[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edge#Verb), [2](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Edging)]

So I wonder how I could use it in this meaning.

The sentences have meant that

> Fighters are often on the edge of getting injuries.
> She is prone to place herself on the verge of threat.
> She has consciously stuck on the verge of feeling the wind.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the slang usage, but even with your explanation I don't find the sentences at all clear.

Comment: Your second versions are better but not perfect. Unlike @KateBunting my immediate thought was that this was some play on the sexual meaning so I would definitely avoid the use of edging unless I was sure it was unambiguous.

Comment: @mdewey, that is, that makes sense if she takes sexual pleasure in threat or the wind? It would also be helpful to know if _edging_ in that sexual meaning intuitively suggests _keeping something on an edge_ or any relation to edges, or is perceived as an idiom. Thanks!

Comment: @malakurta no they do not make any sense in any meaning of _to edge_ of which I am aware.